# Xamarin Cross Platform. Remove back arrow from actionbar for Android Devices

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am using a Master Detail Page and can manage to replace the default app icon with a hamburger icon (For Android) using the following:

```
    NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon((Page)this, "menu_hamburger.png");
```

This displays the icon on the actionbar, but there is still a back arrow to the left of it.

I have tried adding the following code:

```
   NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton((Page)this, false);
```

But this does not work.

Can someone please help me remove this? I am using MVVM.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar((Page)this, false); ?

Comment: @JacobShanley Trouble is he wants to use NavigationBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the end using ActionBar.

In the Xamarin.Droid MainActivity OnCreate Method. Use this line:

```
    Drawable icon = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
    ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(icon);
```

Now in the Code-behind of the view you would like to use, in the constructor add the following line of code:

```
    NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon((Page)this, "menu_hamburger.png");
```

NOTE: Adding a transparent drawable to the MainActivity in Xamarin.Droid, will remove the default back arrow button for all the pages. So you will have to set the image on all the pages